# How to install PHP 7.3 on MXLinux 18?

Tags: php

I want to learn PHP 7.2 or 7.3 on my newly installed MXLinux 18. But After installing the lamp stack by using MX Package Manager, php version is reported to be just PHP 7.0. I would like to know if there is any way to upgrade to or install PHP version 7.3 on my machine. Please help me find a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way by finally being able to view `mxlinux` forums:
[how to upgrade from php 7.0 to php 7.2](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=46823)

Followed the link they had provided there, installed `PHP 7.2` and it is working perfectly fine now. The other thing is that php 7.3 is under development process and I didn't feel it to be correct to be installed except for development and testing purposes.